# Using Console.ReadLine but pre-populating user input

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit text in C# console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565415/edit-text-in-c-sharp-console-application)

I want to prompt the user to enter a string via the console using `Console.ReadLine()` but I want to pre-populate a string that they can then accept, append, or delete and enter a new one.

Something like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Directory:");
Console.Write(@"C:\Temp\");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
```

This obviously doesn't work because they can't delete `C:\Temp` and enter their own directory (and also the input doesn't contain `C:\Temp\`).

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: Yes, I've voted to close my own question. Rather than delete so that it serves as another search point (I searched beforehand but didn't find the other question).